# Azure I deleted VMAccessForLinux Extension on Portal

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, reinstall

As the title, I deleted VMAccessForLinux Extension.
However, there's no way to get back the extension.

How to re-install the extension on my VM?

In the case of using Azure CLI, it get me error like the follow:

---

Wed Feb 24 2016 20:56:17 GMT+0900 (KST):
{ [Error: Invalid update to extension reference for role: Look360VM and reference: VMAccessForLinux.]
  code: 'BadRequest',
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: '36d5f8a1bcd37ce480e26e31a2742249' }
Error: Invalid update to extension reference for role: Look360VM and reference: VMAccessForLinux.
    at Function.ServiceClient._normalizeError (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:815:23)
    at /usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/filters/errorhandlingfilter.js:44:29
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/lib/http/request-pipeline.js:109:14)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:199:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request. (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:1160:14)
    at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:1111:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16

---

It says 'BadRequest'. I don't know why exactly, but it might be I deleted the extension.

Please comment on the solution if you experienced.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the current Azure CLI, always use the utility command `azure vm reset-access` and its parameters to perform this work, assuming you're on ARM deployment. It's simply the easiest way to do this, since you do not have to worry about json stuff....

```
azure vm reset-access --help
help:    Enables you to reset Remote Desktop Access or SSH settings on a Virtual Machine and to reset the password for the account that has administrator or sudo authority.
help:
help:    Usage: vm reset-access [options] <resource-group> <name>
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                             output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                          use verbose output
help:      -vv                                    more verbose with debug output
help:      --json                                 use json output
help:      -g, --resource-group <resource-group>  the resource group name
help:      -n, --name <name>                      the virtual machine name
help:      -u, --user-name <user-name>            the user name
help:      -p, --password <password>              the password
help:      -M, --ssh-key-file <ssh-key-file>      path to public key PEM file or SSH Public key file for SSH authentication (valid only when os-type is "Linux")
help:      -r, --reset-ssh                        Reset the SSH configuration to default
help:      -E, --extension-version <version>      Version of VM Access extension [1.4]
help:      -e, --expiration <expiration>          password expiration
help:      -R, --remove-user <remove-user-name>   Remove a user account with specified name
help:      -s, --subscription <subscription>      the subscription identifier
help:
help:    Current Mode: arm (Azure Resource Management)
```

Comment: Don't know why azure don't list this as a solution ,easy and straightforward, thanks!

Comment: This topic does: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-using-vmaccess-extension/

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact error as you did when using Azure CLI to install the extension to my VM. I haven't identify the root cause yet. But, I have an alternative way to install the extension, using Azure PowerShell instead.

Here is the command:

```
$vm = Get-AzureVm -ServiceName <your cloud service> -Name <your vm>

Set-AzureVMExtension -ExtensionName "VMAccessForLinux" -VM $vm `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" -Version "1.*" | Update-AzureVM
```

After a few diggings, I have found the root cause. You need to specify the "Reference Name" for "VMAccessForLinux", which is "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux". For `azure vm extension set`, by default, it use the name of extension as the reference name, which works for most of the extensions. However, "VMAccessForLinux" is not the case.

Here is the command:

```
azure vm extension set "<your VM>" "VMAccessForLinux" "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" "1.*" -r "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux"
```

Comment: Still getting this: C:\tmp>azure vm extension set "MostM" "VMAccessForLinux" "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" "1.*" -r "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux"
info:    Executing command vm extension set
VM Extension version: 1.5
+ Looking up the VM "VMAccessForLinux"
error:   Virtual machine "VMAccessForLinux" not found under the resource group "MostM"
info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\xxx\.azure\azure.err
error:   vm extension set command failed

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer to enable for a new Resource manager VMs:

```
$RGName = "<Rg name>"
$VmName = "<Vm name>"
$Location = '<VM Location>'

$ExtensionName = 'VMAccessForLinux'
$Publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'
$Version = '1.4'

$PublicConf = '{}'
$PrivateConf = '{
  "username": "<new username>",
  "password": "<new password>",
  "reset_ssh": true
}'

Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMName $VmName -Location $Location -Name $ExtensionName -Publisher $Publisher -ExtensionType $ExtensionName -TypeHandlerVersion $Version -Settingstring $PublicConf -ProtectedSettingString $PrivateConf
```

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/VMAccess for more details.